# Disable flash player for testing

Tags: flash, swfobject

For testing purposes I would like to disable flash player so it doesn't display any swf's anymore. Is there an easy solution for this, or should I uninstall flash player? I used swfobject that displays an image when flash isn't installed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On what browser ? You usually have FlashBlock that is really useful.

Comment: Doesn't matter what browser. Thanks, I'll check this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily on Chrome typing `about:plugins` in the url bar.

Then, search for your flash plugins and click `disable` to disable them. After you're finished, just go back an enabled them again.

Answer (score 0):

With Opera, press F12 and uncheck "Enable plug-ins"

http://help.opera.com/Windows/8.52/en/menus.html#quickprefscontext

You can customize any toolbar with a checkbox with this option if you want a (shorter) shortcut